# "Metadata signature is invalid error" when running Restore-AzureRmApiManagement in Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-api-management, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to restore a backup of API management onto a newly provisioned instance using the Restore-AzureRmApiManagement cmdlet as follows:

```
Restore-AzureRmApiManagement 
      -Name "apimanagementresource" 
      -ResourceGroupName $TargetResourceGroup 
      -StorageContext $StorageAccountContext 
      -SourceContainerName $TargetStorageContainerName 
      -SourceBlobName $ApiManagementBackupName
```

After a few mins it returns the following error:

```
Restore-AzureRmApiManagement : RestoreFailed: Verification failed: 
                                                     metadata signature is invalid
```

It is quite an unhelpful error message and I am yet to find any mention of it in any documentation online.

The backup I am restoring was taken from an API management instance on another subscription, and I am trying to restore it onto a newly provisioned resource.

Could it be that you can only restore a back up on the original resource that it was taken from?

Failing that, can anyone offer any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: could it be that your are backing up and restoring between different pricing tiers? For example, Developer => Standard or Standard => Premium? Just a guess at this point as I could not find anything on this for you either. Also, how old is the backup you are trying to restore?

Comment: @RuSs, it is definitely all on the same pricing tier (developer), the only difference really is that the backup was taken from a different subscription to the one I'm restoring it on. The backup is probably around 2 months old, but now you mention it I seem to remember seeing something about a 30 day expiry on APIM backups somewhere

Comment: The error message is displayed when the calculated hash of the Metadata.xml does not match the hash stored in the file.  I'm not sure what might cause this mismatch.